# Issues unzipping file in Nodejs via a child process, it gives me an error, however when I run the exact command in the child process it works

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, node-modules, unzip

I have a script up at the moment that downloads a zip file from a permalink, unzips it, delete the old version of the file, and then renames the newly unzipped directory.

```
exec("unzip recentDatabase.zip", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(error){
      ...
    }
    if (stderr) {
      ...
    }
    ... 
    exec("rm -r recentDatabase ; mv " + DBname + " recentDatabase");
  })
```

for some reason I get the error : " End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive."

I have made a callback statement with this to make sure that this unzip command only runs when it confirms that the http download is finished, and when I run 'unzip recentDatabase.zip' in the terminal it works perfectly fine, it only has issues when I call it from a child process.

Is there something that im doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the file? `exec("unzip /where/it/lives/in/the/filesystem/recentDatabase.zip", (error, stdout, stderr) => {`?

Comment: yeah I did, also I think I fixed the issue, callbacks don't work with downloads it seems, it call the callback once it properly begins the download, but nothing notifies the script that the download is finished, I added a timeout function to make sure that the download woks properly

Comment: Pleased to hear; instead of a potentially unreliable timer, did you consider using something like [inotify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inotify)? I have no node.js experience, but have made ample use of inotify events from other languages.